# how to graphically view the dependencies in spring application context file

Tags: spring, dependencies

i have a few application context files for an application.
I want to view graphically the dependencies between them.

Is there a free plugin in eclipse or some viewer?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Spring Tool Suite has an editor (Spring Config Editor) to edit the spring context xml files. This Editor can also draw a diagram of the beans (the tab "Beans Graph" of that editor -- see the image below.).

When I remember right, then this functionality is also included in the Eclipse [Spring IDE](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/node/156) Plugin.

---

[image: "Beans Graph" of "Spring Config Editor" in STS]

Comment: This is, alas, all gone now. STS 4 does away with tools for understanding the project…

Answer (score 1):

There's also the [Spring Bean Doc](http://spring-beandoc.sourceforge.net/index.html) project, although it's a bit long-in-the-tooth. I have not used it with Spring 3, so I can't speak for its efficacy for recent versions.