# Java EE: reflect elements relationship between beans and class

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee

I'm new to Java EE and just begin to learn Spring, I wonder whether or not there is a way to show the relationship between the beans and the class who uses the beans.

If there is Main.java, beanA.xml and beanB.xml, classA.java and classB.java, I hope to finally get a diagrame who tells the following things:

1. Main.java calls a beanA who corresponds to classA
2. Main.java calls a beanB who corresponds to classB

It seems like dependency anaylyse.

Comment: This could be related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8081049/how-to-graphically-view-the-dependencies-in-spring-application-context-file

Comment: And this one too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9700282/is-there-a-tool-to-generate-spring-application-context-dependency-diagram-graph

Comment: @fujy that's what I want. thank you!

Comment: @fujy make it an official answer so I can check it.