# Tool to visualize the spring beans?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Tool to visualize the spring bean
There are lot of beans are defined and used in many controllers in a project. The beans are grouped and organized in different files. To trace the url to controller to some bean, need to search 4 or 5 bean id to get the complete path. Are there any tool to parse and visualize these beans as a graph

Comment: I don't think there is any tool available to see the beans as a graph. But you can write your own customized BeanPostProcessor to see which beans are created. This blog post may also help you to get the list of beans - you may need to change the code according to your own need - http://www.captaindebug.com/2014/02/optimising-your-applicationcontext.html#.VwX76vl96M8

Comment: Both IntelliJ and STS provide those features, anything not working for you?

Comment: Intellij is not detecting the spring config file. When i open the Project structure - Modules, Selected the spring under the Project, all the configurations files are showing in red color. I couldn't figure out the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Spring Tool Suite (plugin for Eclipse or standalone) installed, you can see the Beans Graph if you open an Spring XML file and then choose the tab "Beans Graph" (see also [how to graphically view the dependencies in spring application context file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8081049/how-to-graphically-view-the-dependencies-in-spring-application-context-file))

But I think you cannot see the URL mapping there...

Comment: Thank you, I actually verified the Beans graph in STS and Diagrams in Intellij. Both of those plugins showing the diagram for only one file. The configurations in our project are spread across many files.

Comment: they only seem to show xml config files not java annotated configuration.  this is a needed tool for spring architecture.